# QGIS drops KML styling

Tags: qgis, kml, style

Is there a plugin for supporting opening KML files with colors, as currently the KML format is supported, but the colors and styles that comes with it are dropped?

I've created a KML style file:
http://www.files.com/shared/599d872e33689/sierraLeone.kml.zip

Uploading it to KML viewer, it's displaying properly, but in QGIS it fails. The kml viewer site:
http://ivanrublev.me/kml/

Comment: Found a similar subject : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130753/import-file-format-with-colors

Answer (score 4):

I found another way... Hold on it's tricky ! I put here this solution with the main parts you need. It's a bit long to set up compared to your actual work but it can be used for wider sets of data.

- As KML is an XML file, you can [import it into Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-XML-data-6eca3906-d6c9-4f0d-b911-c736da817fa4#bmopen_an_xml_data_file), for example, to read it in a tabular way. I tried that bluntly and got the following :

[image: XML import]

- Let's check in Google Earth the color value. Picture below is in french but you can see the HTML color code (#something)

[image: html color]

- As you can see, the hexadecimal code is in the table (in red), just in front of the name column. Yeah, **we have the name field and the color value**.
- Get all the name and the styleUrl into another sheet.
- Clean the data by [removing duplicates](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-ccf664b0-81d6-449b-bbe1-8daaec1e83c2).
- You should now have only a **flat table with a name and a color column**.

Now you have a choice. Either you extract the RGB values in Excel or in QGIS.
QGIS needs at the end values in R,G,B,A (Red Green Blue Alpha) style.

---

**Prepair the color value in EXCEL**

- In Excel, you will first have to split up the hexa values in 3 with string operators like MID(), then convert them into decimal with HEX2DEC().
- You will then need to reassemble in a string field to match QGIS formating needs in the data defined column for the color.
- See here : **[Convert HEX to RGB in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45833797/convert-hex-to-rgb-in-excel)**

[image: xl hexdec]

---

**Prepair the color value in QGIS**

- In QGIS, import your previous name + color table. Join this to your KML based on the name column :

[image: join in QGIS]

- You will need to create a little function (see below) to convert hexa values to decimal, but it's almost the same logic.
- Put the following code in the function editor, then click on load.

[image: hex2dec]

```
"""
Define new functions using @qgsfunction. feature and parent must always be the
last args. Use args=-1 to pass a list of values as arguments
"""

from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def hex2dex(value1, feature, parent):
    """
        Converts a hex value to decimal
        hex2dec(hexa number)
    """
    return int( value1 ,16)
```

---

- When this is done, you will be able to use it as a new function :

[image: hex2dec expression editor]

---

**Final rendering**

- You need to get to a final color column formated this way :

> Expected input: **string [r,g,b,a]** as int 0-255 Valid input types: string

[image: color field]

- Let's have a try. You need to put the fill color as a data defined field pointing to your formatted color field :

[image: data defined]

- And...Tadaaam !

[image: KML and color and QGIS]

- Comparison with the source file in Google Earth :

[image: source kml]

Comment: I uploaded the file I've made here if you need it  : https://framadrop.org/r/2nnrh03qYy#EO1XtHgjSqpjuPfQAakUeNR7+JgWmOYMqeK7+0Y3ewM=

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question. My research on the subject led to using the **OGR_STYLE** keyword **combined with SQL** but something must be wrong it doesn't work.

The trick is to try and **get the XML style info and put it into a new field** in the SHP file you're writing.

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -SQL "select *, CAST (OGR_STYLE AS Character (255)) AS style from sierraLeone.kml" "sierraLeone.shp" "sierraLeone.kml"
```

This answer is not complete but I haven't found anything further for the moment and my attempts are not successful. Some people seem to achieve the same type of manipulation with Mapinfo, see an example below ([source](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_feature_style.html)):

> "**2.9 Using OGR SQL to transfer the style between the data sources**
>
> We can use the OGR_STYLE special field to extract the feature level
>   style, and ogr2ogr can be used to transfer the style string between
>   the data sources according to the following example:
>
> ```
> ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -sql "select *, OGR_STYLE from rivers"
> rivers.shp rivers.tab
> ```
>
> Without specifying the length of the style field
>   the output driver may truncate the length to a default value.
>   Therefore it may be necessary to specify the target length manually,
>   like:
>
> ```
> ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -sql "select *, CAST(OGR_STYLE AS
> character(255)) from rivers" rivers.shp rivers.tab
> ```
>
> OGR is aware of
>   using the OGR_STYLE field if exists and OGRFeature::GetStyleString
>   will return the value of this field if no style string have been
>   specified programmatically."

See also a similar question to yours discussed here :

- http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-Convert-kml-to-Shapefile-and-conserve-polygon-s-colors-with-Ogr2Ogr-td5010203.html