# QGIS/QDAL: Accessing OGR_STYLE across all layers in a KML file

Tags: qgis, kml, ogr2ogr

I get a regularly updated KML file which I need to pull into QGIS. 
It has different folders/layers (about 12), and features in each folder/layer have different `<styleURL>`s. I need to access each feature's `styleURL` (along with name, description, and the location) for processing in QGIS.

*1st attempt* - just import the KML file inside QGIS. I get one layer per folder (well, lines and points separately), but the styleURL is not an accessible field.

*2nd attempt* by manually running ogr2ogr and using the special field OGR_STYLE:

```
ogr2ogr -f GPKG -oo LIBKML_RESOLVE_STYLE=YES -sql "select *, OGR_STYLE from Boundaries" twinrock_test.gpkg twinrock13.kml
```

Works fine for a single named folder, Boundaries, but I need to run it for all folders in the kml file, as if I just did ogr2ogr -f GPKG twinrock_test.gpkg twinrock13.kml (without the mucking around with OGR_STYLE).

*3rd attempt*:

```
ogr2ogr -f GPKG -oo LIBKML_RESOLVE_STYLE=YES -select Name,description,OGR_STYLE twinrock_test2.gpkg twinrock13.kml
```

Fails since the special field `OGR_STYLE` seems only accessible via -sql, not -select.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Well, no answers in 2.5 weeks, so I did my best: the idea is to essentially use my 2nd attempt above, and then use the Categorized renderer in QGIS (on `OGR_STYLE`) with saved QGIS styles that recreate and improve the KML styling, applies consistently for all folders/layers.

Sharing in PyQGIS in case useful (be gentle, please - started learning Python only this week):

```
from osgeo import ogr, gdal

gdal.UseExceptions() 
ogr.UseExceptions()

# figure out list of folders in kmlfile
kmlLayers = []
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("LIBKML")
kml = driver.Open(kmlfile, 0)
for idx in range(kml.GetLayerCount()):
    kmlLayers.append(kml.GetLayerByIndex(idx).GetName())
del kml

# now iterate through them with gdal.VectorTranslate, using special SQL statement to capture OGR_STYLE as well as other fields, storing in gpkgfile
vtParams = {
    'destNameOrDestDS': gpkgfile
    , 'srcDS': kmlfile
    , 'format': "GPKG" # could use other formats, this is convenient
    , 'options': ['-update','-overwrite','-oo','LIBKML_RESOLVE_STYLE=YES']
    # SQLStatement added below in for loop
}

for layerName in kmlLayers:
    vtParams.update({
        'SQLStatement': 'select *, OGR_STYLE AS Style from "{}"'.format(layerName)
    })
    gdal.VectorTranslate(**vtParams)

# now go on to reload and repaint layers on current map canvas that reference them, as well as to add and conditionally style (based on Style) any new folders added
```

I've also submitted a feature request for QGIS Desktop to pass `OGR_STYLE` on import through `ogr`, which would make this all easier!